# EasyAdmin 4 - generate URL with filter

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I need to redirect my user to CRUD index where filter "STATUS = ACTIVE" is applied.

I've this:

```
$url = $this->adminUrlGenerator
            ->setController(Customer::class)

            ->generateUrl();

return $this->redirect($url);
```

But I can't find a way to add a filter to it. I've tried searching for something like:

```
->setFilter('Status', 'ACTIVE')
```

but without any luck. There is nothing in the docs. How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EasyAdmin handle filters in your url by adding multiple options to handle each filters case.

1. `value` to be compared with
2. `value2` (Example: between value and value2)
3. `comparison` for "equal", "less than", "greater than" etc...

Filtering by **Status** `ACTIVE` would modify your url with

```
&filters[Status][comparison]=%3D&filters[Status][value]=ACTIVE
```

> Note that here %3D is `=` encoded for the url, but using `=` would work as well.

So when using EA AdminUrlGenerator, you can use `->set` to modify options.

You would get:

```
$url = $this->adminUrlGenerator
            ->setController(Customer::class)
            ->set('filters[Status][value]', 'ACTIVE')
            ->set('filters[Status][comparison]', '=')
            ->generateUrl();
```

*I kept the case on **S**tatus, but if your property is in lowercase, do it here as well.*

Comment: It works like a charm. Is it possible to apply it to the Dashboard controller, more beautifully than this?

MenuItem::linkToUrl('Zawieszone','fa fa-hourglass',
                $this->adminurlgenerator
                    ->setController(KlientCrudController::class)
                    ->setAction('index')
                    ->set('filters[Status][value]', 'Zawieszone')
                    ->set('filters[Status][comparison]', '=')
                    ->generateUrl()),

Comment: There is an easyadmin constant for 'index', something like Crud::PAGE_INDEX or something similar which would be a little better. Also, you should not need to use adminUrlGenerator for an easy admin link, don't use linkToUrl (I don't recall the exact method so look into others method to link to an action)

Comment: Nice to know, it may depend on what kind of filter your are using ? I tried again with a text filter and it's `=` (or in the url `%3D`)